# How to get force dump of logs from an application in case of exception

Tags: android, logging, file-permissions, stack-trace

My question comprises 2 parts as below

Part-1
I am getting an exception while writing files in sdcard.

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

in post KitKat phones.
I have already provided the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest.Can someone provide solution or suggestion for above issue.

Part-2
I want to capture the whole stacktrace or dump logs and send these silently to my server . Can some one help me with work flow and suggestions( i.e different approaches).Please note that i dont want to show force stop to the user as some 3rd party apk(like hockey) requires to log the stacktraces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use WRIGHT_EXTERNAL_STORAGE also check this https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Comment: My bad, i wrongly wrote the read permission.I have updated the question. Anyway thanks

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar, I am already using HockeyApp for crash reporting. So i would try to avoid using ACRA with this . Is HockeyApp enables us to log the caught exception or whole stacktrace ?.